# Can't connect to Raspberry pi 4B via WAN IP

Tags: pi-4, internet, port-forwarding, owncloud

I have installed and configured owncloud 2 months ago and port forwarded ports 443 and 80 on my router. Back then it worked flawlessly, but now it does not for some reason. The Owncloud server works on both the LAN IP and "Raspberrypi.local" ip-s, but on the WAN IP it just times out. I have also configured an SSL Cerificate. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: perhaps your internet provider doesn't allow incoming 80 or 443 - many block ports like that (I know in Australia they do unless you ask for them to be allowed) - have you perhaps changed internet provider? Another idea is, are you trying to use the WAN IP from within the LAN? You'll need to configure the router to do such "loopback" or "hairpin NAT" as it is apparently known - https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat

Comment: My friend is going to the IP i provide him, still times out. You are correct, i have changed ISPs, however i tried to connect within 2 different LAN networks that both have ports 443 and 80 forwarded and it still times out. It is possible both of them block traffic, but unlikely. Nevertheless i will contact both of my ISPs to confirm. In the mean time i formatted my Pi's hard drive and completely reinstalled and reconfigured the System but the same problem still occurs.

Comment: try this. forward some other port, say 8080 to the pi, and install nginx (or apache if you're more comfortable with that) and configure it to listen to port 8080 - if that is accessible, then the ISP is blocking 80 and 443

Comment: I do use apache to host my Owncloud server. I have tried what you suggested, but still nothing changes. we try to visit the ip we get from whatismyip.com (on the raspberry) and it still times out no matter what port i forward. The frustrating thing is that it stopped working "out of the blue"

Comment: is this from within the LAN or from the internet that you can't access the web page on the pi?

Comment: It is from the internet. When i visit my local LAN IP, it loads correctly.

Comment: so your ISP is blocking all incoming connections? or maybe your router is not forwarding correctly? or maybe you've configured the router wrong? I'd say whatever the problem is, it's not the pi

Comment: I honestly don't know where to go from here. I have not changed my router's configuration, the router has two port forwarding rules, 443 to 443 on the raspberry's IP and 80 to 80. I tried 443 and 80 to random ports and it made no difference. the ISP's live customer support is clueless, so they advised me to send them a mail, to which they still haven't answered after a week.